# Distribution of in-class and online activities during hybrid teaching after COVID-19

Tags: administration, course-design

Here in Brazil we are slowly returning to face-to-face activities, and this includes university classes. Most proposal suggest that we do this gradually, by first implementing a hybrid teaching system (e.g. with 40% in-class and 60% online activities), and only going back to fully in-person activities after the situation is safer for everyone.

One big problem we are facing during these discussions is how to properly distribute online and in-person acitivites in a way that:

- avoids agglomerations (e.g. at any given time at most 30% of the usual number of students is at the university, when compared to pre-COVID era)
- avoids situations where a students never goes to the university.
- avoids students having in-person classes right after an online one (or vice-versa).
- avoids packed classrooms.

The current best solution seems to be returning labs and final-year courses in the first semester of 2022, then labs and last and next-to-final-year courses in the second semester of 2022, etc., however this does not address the last point.

I am looking for specific guidelines, experiences and results from other countries and universities, when implementing a partial return to in-person activities.

The university I work at, [UFSC](https://en.ufsc.br), has 5 campi and ~40,000 students.

(I also appreciate descriptions of other experiences, not involving hybrid learning, although those will probably not be adopted here.)

Thank you very much in advance.

---

Comment: I'll guess you just need to experiment. For a multi-campus university with over 35,000 students it is a hard problem in the best case and not many people have much experience with it yet.